# Infering generic type without creating new instance

Tags: java, syntax, generic-type-argument

```
private HashMap<Object, Object> attribute = new HashMap<>();

public <T> T attributeAs(Object key, T as){
    Object ans = attribute.get(key);
    return ans == null ? null : (T) ans;
}
```

method:

```
ModuleM m = (ModuleM) player.attribute.get("module_m");
```

Apart from that method, is there any way to return a type without creating a new class instance, i.e this:

```
ModuleM m = person.attributeAs("module_m", new ModuleM());
```

Because when using the above you're creating a whole new instance and if ModuleM was a huge class with a lot of data, then that would affect processing power/speed correct?

(Remeber I want ModuleM not Class< ModuleM>)

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to send an instance:

```
public <T> T attributeAs(Object key){
    Object ans = attribute.get(key);
    return (T) ans;
}
```

The compiler will infer types based on the assignment on the invocation:

```
ModuleM attribute = person.attributeAs("module_m");
```

But of course, you might get class cast exceptions as your map supports `<Object, Object>` entries, in the case where the actual instance is not compatible with the concrete target type. That's because a call such as:

```
String attribute = person.attributeAs("lastName") //probably OK
```

or

```
String attribute = person.attributeAs("module_m") //probably problematic
```

would also be legal, but potentially incompatible.